# Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect mssql server 2008 using jdbc connection.
My connection url is like

jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:1433/dbname;user=username;password=password

However I get the above mentioned exception when I try to execute a stored procedure through prepared statement

I have enabled TCP/IP and Named pipes.
I have disabled firewall.

What could be the issue.

I found out it was because the following error occurs
"ole/db provider returned message login timeout expired"...

but not sure why this happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The linked server was configured with wrong authentication values. Hence when I tried to connect to the linked server it threw authentication exception which in turn throws above mentioned exception.

Creating a linked server with proper authentication values fixed the issue.

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar problem, could you explain what you mean by "proper authentification values"? I tried several different parameters and the linked server still cannot connect

Comment: Proper authentication values refers to valid remote login username and password details of the database to which linked connection is to be made

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, maybe the problem is related with DNS.
I fixed the problem creating the linked server with the IP Address instead of the server's name.