# Connecting to SQL Server using PHP, ODBC, and Windows authentication

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, php, windows, odbc

I'm trying to use PHP to connect to an ODBC data source using Windows authentication.  I can connect just fine to the server in SQL Server so I know it's running.  When I try to run the command

```
$link = odbc_connect("my_odbc","","");
```

I get the error:

> "Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: 
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]
> Login failed for user ''., SQL state 28000 in SQLConnect in C:\Users..."

I tried:

```
$link = odbc_connect("Driver={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};   
        Server='my_odbc';Integrated Security=SSPI","","");
```

Which returned the message:

> Warning: odbc_connect(): SQL error: 
> [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server]
> Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]. , SQL state 08001 in SQLConnect in C:\Users..."

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

- `my_odbc` is a SQL Server (2008) on a different machine. I don't have admin privileges on that database so I can't change anything on that end (such as enabling SQL Server authentication).
- I am running Windows 7 and using PHP Version 5.6.12
- `phpinfo()` indicates that ODBC Support is enabled as well as `pdo_sqlsrv` support

Comment: Integrated Security=SSPI in the connection string tells the ODBC driver to use the current user for the running process. Perhaps specific user id and password in the connection string.

Comment: Are you sure the identity that your code is using is granted rights to connect to the SQL Server? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/02/10/sql-server-driver-for-php-understanding-windows-authentication.aspx

Comment: Why are you using ODBC instead of using the SQL Native driver? e.g. using sqlsrv_connect() - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296205%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: The error is saying "Login failed for user " and you're not passing in a username or password.  Shouldn't you be doing `$link = odbc_connect("my_odbc", "your_user", "your_pass"); ` with your SQL Server username/password?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should try PDO (the performance difference isn't that great) with SQLsrv plugin (this what I'm using to connect to my other boss' software which use SQL Server 2008 database):

```
$connection = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=" . $this->sourceServer . ";Database=" . $this->sourceDB, $this->sourceUser, $this->sourcePW);
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
```

You can download the plugin here

https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=36434

In Xampp, you must copy the dll in that folder:

```
C:\xampp\php\ext
```

And you must add that line to your php.ini

```
extension = php_pdo_sqlsrv_56_ts.dll
```

**Note**: Don't forget to restart your server so it can take in account the new php.ini file.

Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 3):

This error is a General Error that arises due to unable to establish connect to the server for some reasons. Its important to know what server are you using with PHP and the application used with it. Example Apache, Xampp or Wamp etc.

Here are somethings you could try like.

Let me brief, below are the reference links.

- Check whether it pings
- Enable TCP/IP connection SQL Server Configuration if not enabled. To do so, Open `SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Network
  Configuration->Protocols for SQL server->TCP/IP(set to enabled)`.
  Restart SQL services.
- Enable Remote Connection from server
- Open the Port,  To do so `Windows Firewall Settings-> Exceptions -> add a Port (Name:SQL;Port:1433;TCP) then from Exceptions tick SQL` and save.
- Enable running browser services.`SQL Server Configuration Manager -> SQL Server Services - > SQL Server Browser` set to running.
- defining Port in connection string
- add instance name with machine name if more than one instance is being used

sample

```
$user = 'username';
$pass = 'password';
//Use the machine name and instance if multiple instances are used
$server = 'serverName\instanceName';
//Define Port
$port='Port=1433';
$database = 'database';

$connection_string = "DRIVER={ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server};SERVER=$server;$port;DATABASE=$database";
$conn = odbc_connect($connection_string,$user,$pass);
```

here are useful links that i found regarding the issue

[resolving could not open a connection to sql server-errors](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2340/resolving-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-errors/)

[sql server provider named pipes provider error](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/)

Have a look at these links too

[Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [53]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15152107/named-pipes-provider-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-53)

Comment: I only found your example of useage of the port. Where did you find it?

Comment: hehe. its been six years. i dont remember.

Answer (score 2):

Someone had the same error message and asked and answered his own question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19620772/3585500).

To quote...

*I´m sorry for the troubles.*

*The problem was, that I was using SQL Server Native Client 11.0 as driver. I switched it to SQL Server and now it works :/*

*Hopefully this at least helps someone, being in a similar problem....*

Answer (score 2):

A significant omission from your question is how you are running PHP and with which credentials.

Assuming you are using IIS or Apache (or another web server), then your PHP process is probably running under the local system account:

[image: IIS service properties]
[image: Apache service properties]

Since this account is *local* it doesn't have any authorisation to access your *remote* SQL Server.

You could alter the IIS/Apache service to run with the credentials (yours?)  that are authorised to connect to SQL Server, but be aware this might cause other permissions issues with the service as well as being a problem if you change your password in the future.

Try running a test script from the command line (which should run with your credentials by default) to determine where the problem is:

```
php -r "var_dump(odbc_connect(...));"
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the regedit HKLM/SOFTWARE/ODBC

what is your folder name ?

If there is a "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" then you have to write your php code like

```
odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};Server=ip;Database=db;", "user", "pass");
```

However some of the server like server 2008 will be record this odbc like

```
ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server
```

Then you have to replace SQL Server Native Client 11.0 by ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an ODBC interface first. In principle, this should also work without a user and pw. If defined in your interface.

```
$pdo = new PDO('odbc:dsnName','user','pw');
```

Answer (score -2):

Enable in IIS on Manager PHP o PDO_ODBC:

I have authenticated by Windows with following PHP statement:

$ Conn = new PDO ("odbc: Driver = {SQL Server}; Server = JAMILI-PC \ SQLEXPRESS; null; null");

I am using Windows 2008.

I hope it solves your problem.

Comment: That doesn't look like valid PHP syntax?